# Can't get Dynamic Linq to work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to work with the Dynamic Linq library for querying my entity framework data source. I have added the correct package to my project and have used the following syntax

```
 var salesEntities = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate).Where(d => d.DateKey <= endDate)
                                    .Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID)
                                    .Where("StoreID==@0",1)
                                    .ToList();
```

I have also tried

```
 .Where("StoreID=1")
```

based on the example I found on the ScottGu blog post that most dynamic query SO questions seem to suggest. Can anyone help me see what I am missing to make this work?

It doesnt produce and error it just fails to return any data at all.

Comment: I have just created a simple test sample, the reason I need to use Dynamic Linq is because users need to be able to select 1 or more stores to view dynamically at runtime, that is why the .Where() for StoreID is seperate from the others

Comment: The last time I checked linq, it does not support that kind of syntax. You may need to build your own predicates ... Predicates are basically used to create dynamic queries... think like a multi filter search as a possible scenario. Here is a good example: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c42694/dynamic-query-in-linq-using-predicate-builder/... also C# 6.0 has already a `PredicateBuilder` that you may want to check.

Comment: Could you try `.Where(s => s.StoreID == 1)` ? Does it return data?

Comment: yes   .Where(s => s.StoreID == 1) returns data

Comment: Source code for the documentation of Dynamic LINQ can be found [here](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/tree/master/web/DynamicLinqWebDocs).

Comment: @DavidEspino LINQ methods on `IQueryable<T>` take expressions which can be constructed in two ways: compiler-generated -- `.Where(x => x.StoreID = 1)`, and built at runtime using static methods in the [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, such as `.Constant`, `MakeMemberAccess` and `Parameter`. The [Dynamic LINQ library](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/) allows a third option -- strings which are then converted into expressions.

Comment: Thanks @ZevSpitz for the tip

Comment: @DavidEspino I've expanded on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40603794/111794).

Comment: hey @ZevSpitz... I know its a bit off topic, but do you know if there is a performance price using the dynamic query library vs an `on the fly` built predicate? Just curious about it :)

Comment: @DavidEspino In either case there is a cost in generating the expression, as well as a certain cost in each call of the expression. My instinct is that the time the library spends parsing the string into an expression, is relatively small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Are you sure you need Dynamic LINQ for this?

```
List<int> storeIDs = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
var salesEntities = dashboardEntity.FactSales
    .Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate)
    .Where(d => d.DateKey <= endDate)
    .Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID)
    .Where(c => storeIDs.Contains(c.StoreID))
    .ToList();
```

---

**Long version**

LINQ allows for compiler-generated expressions:

```
IQueryable<FactSales> qry;
qry = qry.Where(x => x.DateKey >= startDate);
```

If the expressions need to change at runtime, it is possible to build the expression using static methods in the [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
//using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;

//x
var parameter = Parameter(typeof(FactSale));

//x.DateKey
var dateKey = MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(FactSales).GetProperty("DateKey"));

//(the value in startDate, as if it had been written in)
var startDateConst = Constant(startDate);

//x.DateKey >= (value of startDate)
var comparison = GreaterThanOrEqual(dateKey, startDateConst);

//x => x.DateKey >= (value of startDate)
var lmbd = Lambda<Func<FactSale,bool>>(comparison, new [] {prm});

//pass the expression into the Queryable.Where method
qry = qry.Where(lmbd);
```

The Dynamic LINQ library (whose latest incarnation can be found [here](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/)) allows generating expressions using strings:

```
IQueryable<FactSales> qry;
qry = qry.Where("DateKey >= @0", startDate);
```

Dynamic LINQ is extremely useful when the expression is not known at compile time, but in this case, the expression is known at compile time (in this case, using the [`List<T>.Contains` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Therefore I don't see any reason to use Dynamic LINQ here.

N.B. I still don't know why this doesn't work:

```
var qry = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where("StoreID = 1");
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew about the functionality of .Contains this has been a great help!

Comment: @NateGreene I've expanded on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if you sorted this out but I just noticed your reply to my comment.

I think what you are missing is `=` instead of `==` while comparing `StoreID`.

```
var salesEntities = dashboardEntity.FactSales.Where(d => d.DateKey >= startDate).Where(d => d.DateKey <= endDate)
                                .Where(c => c.CompanyID == companyID)
                                .Where("StoreID = @0",1)
                                .ToList();
```